# FileNotFoundError while using get_image_uri() in SageMaker

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, data-science, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to import the machine learning algorithm container (XGBOOST), the following code doesn't seem to work:

```py
from sagemaker.amazon.amazon_estimator import get_image_uri

container = get_image_uri(boto3.Session().region_name, 'xgboost')
```

I get the following error saying the file doesn't work:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker/image_uri_config/xgboost.json'
```

I also used a 'linear-learner' in place of the 'xgboost' but I still got the same error. So, is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

It has been a while since the question was asked, but it may be helpful to currently clarify how it works.

This API in newer versions is [deprecated](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/v2.html#image-uri-functions-e-g-get-image-uri) for 2.x version of the SageMaker Python SDK.

A new function called [image_uris.retrieve](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/utility/image_uris.html#module-sagemaker.image_uris) is now used:

```py
from sagemaker import image_uris

image_uris.retrieve(framework='xgboost', region=your_region, version=version)
```